# why selenium doesn't work when i deploy a GitHub file on railaway?

Tags: github, selenium-webdriver, railway

when i deploy the program i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
wbe = webdriver.Chrome("directory/chromedriver",options=chromeOptions)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
wbe = webdriver.Chrome("directory/chromedriver",options=chromeOptions)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

i tried with this code:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless=chrome')
wbe = webdriver.Chrome("directory/chromedriver",options=chromeOptions)
```